# How to know if Appium is running with Python or Windows command?

Tags: python-3.x, appium, appium-android, python-appium

ENVIRONMENT:

Pyhon 10

Windows11

I have some issues with my appium python code. I suspect Appium server was not running. I am searching a way (in Python or with a Windows command) to know if Appium server is running fine.

I searched for a solution here and in Google but I couldn't find a piece of code in Python, neither a Windows command.

Does anyone know how to check if Appium server is running withou issue?

Comment: You can use the following command to check if the Appium server is running on port 4723:

`netstat -an | findstr :4723`
This command will list all the open ports on your computer. If the Appium server is running, you will see a line that starts with TCP and has the port number 4723 in it.